# How to pass a frame to embedded ViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, frame, segue

When i make a container view in StoryBoard i set constraints to it. Then i put embed segue to my embedded `UIViewController`.
If my embedded ViewController is `UITableViewController` it arranges it's view automatically. But when it is a `UIViewController` it sets itself a frame of standard size (0, 0, 320, 568).

I tried to pass the values of the container view in my root VC `viewDidLoad`. But realised then that my embedded VC instantiates itself before root VC `viewDidLoad` is called.

Here is a code in my proxy controller that is actually embedded - it switches then to one of several view controllers according to situation. Here is the code that is executed in prepareForSegue method:

```
[self addChildViewController:segue.destinationViewController];
UIView* destView = ((UIViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).view;
destView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
destView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:destView];
[segue.destinationViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Please post the code you use to instantiate the embedded vc

Comment: What size is the embedded view controller in the storyboard? I'm talking about the separate view controller, not the container view.

Comment: @jrturton i set fixed simulated size to it, so in my storyboard it has the same size as my container view

Comment: That code you've added is a little disturbing. You shouldn't be doing anything with the destination view controller's view in prepareForSegue - the segue does all that for you.

Comment: I don't see a question. What's the question?

Comment: The question is in the header, @matt

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided should not be inside your 'prepareForSegue' method. The prepareForSegue will do everything for sizing the viewcontroller view frame for you! If you want to add the child viewcontroller programmatically you can try the following (just changed the order of the lines where you assign the view frame):

```
[self addChildViewController:segue.destinationViewController];
UIView* destView = ((UIViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).view;
destView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:destView];
[segue.destinationViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
destView.frame = self.view.bounds; //  <------ try to assign the view frame at last
```

If this is not the right solution, you can try to change the child viewcontroller view frame in the 'viewDidLayoutSubviews' method

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.frame = yourframe; 
}
```

Comment: i do all those preparations because i use my own custom segue from proxy controller (the one that is actually embedded) to the viewController i need to present at the moment.
Unfortunately the changes you suggested do not work for me

Comment: try to remove the segue from the storyboard and add the child viewcontroller programmatically. You can create your child viewcontroller by calling `[self.storyboard insrantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"your_id"];` and then set its view frame